# Смена цветовой гаммы сайта

Tags: css

Идея такова: создать на сайте градиент цветов (картинка) 
Пользователь кликнет в какую-нить точку на картинке, и какой-то участок сайта окрасится в этот цвет. Что-то в этом роде нужно реализовать на сайт. Такое возможно?

Comment: Да, возможно.

Comment: с помощью чего реализовать можно?

Comment: js+css вот пример http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Answer (score 1):

Ответ из комментариев:

Такое возможно сделать с помощью *JS + CSS*.

Пример: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/.